# Does the location of the ballast tank on a submarine matter?

Tags: fluid-statics

To my knowledge ballast tanks on submarines are located at the bottom.  How important is the location of the tank?  Let's do a thought experiment.  Let's imagine a submarine with a space in its hull between the otter and inner skin.  It tries to dive by filling this void with water, but would this not just create a smaller inner submarine and the outer skin essentially being a weight outside of the submarine.  Presumably this weight was not enough to sink it when the space was empty so why would filling the space make the vessel sink?

Comment: Before filling the gap with water, the "smaller submarine" had the weigth of the outer skin pushing it down, but the empty space (the void) pushing it up, due to buoyancy. If you remove that part of buoyancy, independently of the weight of the outer skin, it could sink.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: If you tell me that I got your point, I can make it an answer!

Comment: Yes.  I expect it's the correct answer.  It also implies that a submarine lighter than water could never dive, but I guess that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call the "void" the space between the otter and inner skin and the "smaller submarine" the inner skin and what is inside it.

So we have three parts: the outer skin, the void, and the smaller submarine. The first and the third are rigdly connected.

Before filling the void with water, the smaller submarine is subject to these forces:

1. its own weight, pushing it down;
2. the weigth of the outer skin, also pushing it down;
3. the empty space (the void), which indirectly pushes it up, due to buoyancy;
4. the buoyancy due to the volumes of the outer skin and of the smaller submarine.

If you remove that part of buoyancy, independently of the weight of the outer skin, the whole submarine and the smaller submarine could sink.

Comment: This implies that if the outer skin were made of wood or some other substance less dense than water filling the ballast space would not cause it to dive?

Comment: I slightly corrected the answer. If the average density of the outer skin and of the smaller submarine are smaller than water, then the whole will never sink. Both are contributing to buoyancy and both are contributing to weigth force. If the outer skin is light but the smaller submarine is heavy enough, it can still sink.

Comment: Suppose you put the tank back into the submarine in the usual place but the tank is made from an equal amount of wood as the outer skin was made of?

Comment: Let us see if I understand. We have the outer skin, the smaller submarine, and, in the void, you put an object with the same mass and volume of the outer skin. If so, depending on the masses and volumes, the whole stuff could either sink or float.